# How let loop of buttons comunicate to each other

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a Matching game using alphabets. So the game has three levels. If the user chooses the level 1, a loop for stars to create a table of buttons 4*4 which means 16 boxes. My problem is: I want to make this order >> if the user clicks on the first box randomly( for exemple it appears the lettes A). Then click on the second box and shows the same letter, then keep them visible ,else setVisible = false.
Bare in mind that i am usuing only one button + loop and an String array of letters.

here is my code:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You said "Here is my code:" but didn't include any code...

Comment: Your JButton actionListener method has to keep track of state,  The first time it's executed, the method saves the character from the button.  The second time it's executed, the method gets the character, compares it with the saved character, and if they're equal, does the matching logic.